# Firebase Query limitToLast doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase Database there are values stored under push keys and I'm trying to retrieve these values by their keys starting from the **last 10 of them**. 
The problem is **it doesn't start from the key** at last 10th position **but from a specific key**. **That key is** the one that this code has been first initialized, and it was the first of last 10th as it should be. But new data has been added and **it ignores it** even after reinstalling, restarting the app.
If I change the number to something else then it works fine until I add new message to database. Then same thing happens for that number.

Note: ConversationPushID ( string )that has been passed to conversationsRef is correct and data structure is correct, just sharing them for reassurance, I checked it.

***Query code:***

```
 final  DatabaseReference conversationsRef = firebaseInstance.rootRef
                        .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_conversations))
                        .child(ConversationPushID);

Query getLastMessagesQuery = conversationsRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(10);

                        getLastMessagesQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snap)
                                    {

                                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snap.getChildren())
                                            {
                                                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

                                                String messageKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                                                messageList.add(message);

                                            }         
                                        getLastMessageFromListener = false;
                                        setListenerForLastMessage();                                        
                                    }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                                    {

                                    }
                            });
```

***Additional Information*** ( there is another query is being assigned right after this one, writing just in case there is a connection. Because this bug doesn't makes sense at all

```
private void setListenerForLastMessage()
            {

              final  DatabaseReference conversationsRef = firebaseInstance.rootRef
                        .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_conversations))
                        .child(ConversationPushID);


                getLastMessageQuery = conversationsRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
                lastMessageListener = new ChildEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                            {
                                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);

                                if (getLastMessageFromListener)
                                    {
                                        messageList.add(message);

                                    }
                                getLastMessageFromListener = true;
                            }
                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                            {
                            }
                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                            }
                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                            {
                            }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {
                            }
                    };
                getLastMessageQuery.addChildEventListener(lastMessageListener);
            }
```

[image: Data Structure]

Comment: If there's nothing wrong with your `conversationsRef` then this is very difficult to tell with this, what's going wrong actually.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit it's declared right before Query in local scope of the function. I've added one more detail to question, maybe it helps.

Comment: it is difficult to tell what's going wrong without the full code, it would be better if you could just attach your database structure and tell what you want to retrieve, I can write you a code which might work.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Sure thing, gonna add in couple minute. My edit that I was talking about is finished now if you want to check.

Comment: I don't think another query would interfere with it, unless they both fire at same time, which should not be happening.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Agreed, it's not even initialized before this code. Only way for this bug to make sense is: if the thread-scope tha  this listener has been created would be still alive after reinstalling the app or restarting it and after that it'd still reference that old one which completely non sense. Because it's the same node key that it's starting from all time is the one that it had been initialized when working correctly and getting only the last 10 data.

Comment: So what do you want to retrieve from your firebase structure you've just attached.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I want to retrieve last 10 push keys along with their value, which is working without a problem except the " last 10 " part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183274/discussion-between-mustafa-and-pradyumandixit).

Comment: @Mustafa you're using addListenerForSingleValueEvent() which will only listen to the reference location it is attached to for once.So in order to keep listening to query or database reference it is attached to you've to use addValueEventListener()

Comment: @Shehroz I know and that's not what this is about. I'm calling this again when I start the app so data is already there after it has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when Firebase offline capabilities is enabled.

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

To **solve it** keep the DatabaseReference that you are querying **synced** like this:

```
  conversationsRef.keepSynced(true);
```